# MySQL resultset to java array

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I'm not doing very well with what I'm trying to do at the moment. The aim is to to get all information from a MySQL table and put it into an array. Once into an array I will use the priority queue in java and try to get it to work with that.... but that's not the issue I'm stuck on at the moment.

public static void array(String args[]) {
      // create priority queue

```
   try { 
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project"; 
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","nbuser"); 

        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT user_id,s_date,e_date,d_date,department,projectname,projectapplication FROM booking");
        ResultSet rs; 
        rs=stmt.executeQuery();

                  List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        while(rs.next()) {
        User user = new User(); //issue here with non-static variable
        user.userid(rs.getString("user_id"));
        user.s_date(rs.getObject("s_date"));
        user.e_date(rs.getObject("e_date"));
        user.d_date(rs.getObject("d_date"));
        user.department(rs.getObject("department"));
        user.projectname(rs.getObject("projectname"));
        user.projectapplication(rs.getObject("projectapplication"));
        user.priority(rs.getObject("priority"));

        userList.add(user);
     }

        conn.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    } 
}
```

The aim is to get it to run through all the different sections in the table and populate them into an array, but I'm stuck on populating the array.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

EDIT:

```
public class User {
public String userid;
public String s_date;
public String e_date;
public String d_date;
public String department;
public String projectname;
public String projectapplication;
public int priority;

    private void userid(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    private void s_date(Object object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    private void e_date(Object object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    private void d_date(Object object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    private void department(Object object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    private void projectname(Object object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    private void projectapplication(Object object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    private void priority(Object object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

similar to this?

Comment: You're selecting a lot of fields. Which of them need to be added to array?

Comment: It would be far better and easier if you can use an ORM like JPA. Look for it's implementation that suits you, like, Hibernate, EclipseLink, whatever. They will be easier to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `User` class with the appropriate fields in the SQL table and keep each user in a list.

```
  List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
  while(rs.next()) {
     User user = new User();
     user.setId(rs.getString("user_id"));
     user.setStartDate(rs.getTimestamp("s_date");
     ....
     userList.add(user);
  }
  return userList;
```

**EDIT**:

```
  class User {
   private String id;
   private Date startDate;
   //other fields need to be declared as well as their setter methods

   public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
      this.startDate = startDate;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
  }
```

I would also recommend to take a look at `JPA` and `Hibernate`.

Comment: User class like added above in my edit? so from there on would it be a case of user.(stringname)rs.getObject("....") ? bit unsure in regards to this

Comment: It depends on the fields, for example if you keep date fields as `timestamp` in db, I would go with `Date` class not `String`

Comment: you can use `rs.getString(fieldname)` or you can use `rs.getObject(fieldname)` and cast it afterward

Comment: I've editted my class in the edit section then implemented your function in the original question but commented in where I'm having an error, also is the class right or am I completely off track (most likely case)

Comment: instead of declaring your `array()` method as `static`, you can declare your method as `public List<User> array()` and return the list you are creating `(userList)`

Comment: It is better practice to name `setter` methods with `set` prefix with field name. For example; `setId`, `setDepartmant` ..

Comment: Do all your fields are `varchar` in db?

Comment: Well, since you declared your fields as `public`, no need for `setter` methods. You can access them by simply `user.id`

Comment: Some are DATE but I was having issues setting then as DATE in the class, I will try what you've suggested when I'm back later on, any chance you could edit your suggestions into your original post if possible?

Comment: `rs.getTimestamp(fieldname)` works fine with `Date` since `java.sql.Timestamp` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`. Post is updated.